# How to I create two containers with different backgrounds?

Tags: html, css, containers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php)

I can't seem to find a way to accomplish this properly.  I have two containers.  In one container I want to use a background image that will take over the entire top half horizontally and then I want to use a second container and color it red.  This will take over the bottom half horizontally.

I tried this:

HTML:

```
 <div class="container1">
     Some text and other divs go here. This is where the background will be an image.  
 </div>
 <div class="container2">
     Some text will also here along with divs. This is where I want to use the red background.
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
 .container1 {
      background-image: url('img.png');
      width:100%;
  }
  .container2 {
      width: 100%;
      color: #990000;
  }
```

The problem is that for the image container I am left with whitespace on the top,
 bottom, left, and right.

How do I solve this?

Comment: I think that background image is repeated by default! so How could you get whitespace there?

Comment: For one you're not defining a height on either. So the concept of "half" is unknown. Secondly, use firebug or developer tools to check the parents of these containers. I bet there's padding interfering

Comment: Is the whitespace inside `.container1` or outside?  What is `img.png`?  Are you sure the white is not part of the image?

Comment: Do you want the image to repeat or do you want it to size itself to the width of the div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set padding and margins to 0.  Most experienced UI developers will use what is known as a CSS reset, to eliminate any browser-specific default stylesheet behaviors (like giving padding.

For your purpose a basic CSS reset of:

```
body { padding: 0px; margin: 0px;}
div { padding: 0px; margin: 0px; }
```

at the beginning of your CSS file, should help.

Also, CSS `color` is related to teh text color, not the background color.  You need to use `background-color`.

Comment: Thanks @mike.  That worked.  I do have a follow up question.  Doing this made the image only take over half the page.  But let's say I wanted to extend it's vertical coverage by 20px, how would I do it? I used <br> tags to extend it.  Is there another way?

Comment: @KPO you could set the height explicitly with `height` CSS property.

Comment: Thanks that worked too.  Is there any place you would recommend me to learn excellent CSS from? I am a beginner.  Whatever I know which is on an amateur level, i learned just to do things so not really an expert.

Answer (score 1):

Because you've not defined **half** properly, I'll say your code is okay with the exception of `color` should be `background-color`; see it working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/TkBxH/

If you mean half in terms of screen then you need to use *absolute positioning*, the CSS would be

```
.container1, .container2 {
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    height:400px; /* based on screen size */
}
.container1 {
    top: 0;
}
.container2 {
    bottom: 0;
}
```

---

Edit: If you don't mind the absolute positioning on `<body>` (parent of `.container1, .container2`) you can avoid having to use a px value

```
body { /* Force <body> to fill screen */
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
}
.container1, .container2 {
    height:50%;
}​
```